# How to find the EndDate from a set of given inputs

Tags: c#, datetime, logic

I am struggling with a datetime problem where I am given a set of inputs and I need to find the EndDate by using those inputs. I am trying my best to solve this, but since I am running out of time, I landed up here. So someone who already might have faced this problem or someone with a solution could let me know one.

**Problem Explanation:**

The Concept is a Weekly schedule of a live class streaming application. The teacher has scheduled a weekly class from a specific start date.

Let's say, the start date is from 18th April, 2021 and the teacher selects 3 days per week(Monday, Tuesday & Wednesday) each with different class duration(By duration I mean that, We have the class start time of that day and the length of the class in hours and minutes).

- Start Date: 18th April, 2021
- Total days per week: 3
- Days: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
- Total duration per day: 3 hrs and 30 minutes
- Total duration per week: 10 hours 30 minutes (Aggregated = Mon + Tue + Wed)
- Max duration that the user cannot exceed: 50 hrs

Ok! Now we shall repeatedly add the TDPD(3 hrs and 30 minutes) to the start date until we reach 50 hrs and find which date it has landed upon(the end date).

What I have tried so far?

```
int totalWeeks = 0;
int totalHoursPerWeek = 3;
int totalHoursAdded = 0;
int maxHours = 50;
for(int i = totalHoursPerWeek; i <= maxHours; i += totalHoursPerWeek)
{
    totalHoursAdded += i;
    totalWeeks++;
}
```

Once the loop ends, I have the total week value.

```
DateTime endDate;
if(totalHoursAdded == maxHours)
{
    //My problem is solved, as there is no remaining time pending
    endDate = currentDate.AddDays(totalWeeks * 7);
}
else
{
    // I have some pending hours
    int pendingHours = maxHours - totalHoursAdded;

    //How do I proceed with this pendingHours? how to add this to the 
    //specific days per week and find the end date? I am stuck here...
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper. Yes u r right! I just post it as an example. Anyways I'll correct it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confident this can be done with some carefully thought-out math with dates, however below may be termed the lazy way out. This approach only needs the starting date, a list of days of the week that the class meets, i.e., Monday, Tuesday etc.…, the duration of the class in hours and minutes, and finally the max total hours and minutes that are required.

From my understanding, given the above info, we want to know, given that start date and the days of the week the class meets…

> on what Date will the LAST class be that fulfills the max total hours.

To simplify this, one thing that will come in handy is knowing...

> *“how many classes are needed to fulfill the MAX requirement”.*

In other words, if we know how many classes are needed to fulfill the max requirement, then this should make things easier.

Computing the total number of classes needed to fulfil the max requirement, can be found by dividing the max requirement by the class duration. If the division produces a remainder, then this would mean that one (1) additional class would be needed to fulfil the max requirement.

Therefore, if we have both the class duration and max duration variables as `Timespan` objects, then, we could divide the `TimeSpan` objects via their respective `Tick` properties and return how many classes are needed to fulfil the max requirement. This method may look something like…

```
private int GetTotalNumberOfClassesNeeded(TimeSpan classDuration, TimeSpan totalDuration) {
  double td = totalDuration.Ticks / (double)classDuration.Ticks;
  int totalClasses = (int)Math.Truncate(td); // <- get the whole portion
  if (Math.Floor(td) != td) {
    totalClasses++;  // <- there is a fractional part - 1 more class needed
  }
  return totalClasses;
}
```

Next, we need to compare the `DayOfWeek` for a date with the `DayOfWeek` for the class. Therefore, is what we can do is create a `List<DayOfWeek>` … a list of `DayOfWeek` objects that the class is in session. We will use this list to check and see if a particular date’s day of week is IN that list. Therefore, in this example, the days of the week the class meets are a simple comma delimited `string`. Given this `string`, the code would parse out the days and return the proper list of `DayOfWeek` objects to compare with. This method may look something like…

```
private List<DayOfWeek> GetDaysOfWeekForClasses(string daysOfWeek) {
  List<DayOfWeek> classesDOW = new List<DayOfWeek>();
  string[] splitArray = daysOfWeek.Split(',');
  DayOfWeek dow;
  for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.Length; i++) {
    switch (splitArray[i].Trim()) {
      case "Monday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Monday;
        break;
      case "Tuesday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
        break;
      case "Wednesday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
        break;
      case "Thursday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
        break;
      case "Friday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Friday;
        break;
      case "Saturday":
        dow = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        break;
      default:
        dow = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        break;
    }
    classesDOW.Add(dow);
  }
  return classesDOW;
}
```

That is pretty much all we need. The general idea is this… we start by setting an `int` variable `curClassCount` to zero (0). In addition, we will create a `DateTime` object `tempDate` that is initialized with the starting date. Lastly, we will create a list of `DateTime` objects `scheduledClasses` which will get filled with the dates of the classes. We will start a `while` loop with the condition to continue as long as `curClassCount` is less than the total number of classes needed.

In each iteration of the loop a check is made to see if the `tempDate`’s `DayOfWeek` is one of the class’s `DayOfWeek.` … if it is, then we add that date to the `scheduledClasses` list and increment `curClassCount`. Finally increment `tempDate` by one (1) day, then start the loop over. Eventually, the `curClassCount` will equal the number of classes needed. This code may look something like…

```
while (curClassCount < totalNumberOfClassesNeeded) {
  if (ClassDaysOfWeek.Contains(tempDate.DayOfWeek)) {
    scheduledClasses.Add(tempDate.Date);
    curClassCount++;
  }
  tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Putting all this together by droping a `DateTimePicker, four (4)` TextBoxes, a `Button` and a multi-line `TextBox` onto a new `Winforms .Net` `Form` may look something like…

[image]

Using the code below should complete the example.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2021, 4, 18);
  TextBoxTotDaysPerWeek.Text = "3";
  textBoxClassDays.Text = "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday";
  textBoxClassDuration.Text = "00:03:00:00";
  textBoxMaxDuation.Text = "02:02:00:00";
}

private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DateTime StartDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
  TimeSpan.TryParse(textBoxClassDuration.Text.Trim(), out TimeSpan ClassDuration);
  TimeSpan.TryParse(textBoxMaxDuation.Text.Trim(), out TimeSpan MaxDuration);
  int totalNumberOfClassesNeeded = GetTotalNumberOfClassesNeeded(ClassDuration, MaxDuration);
  List<DayOfWeek> ClassDaysOfWeek = GetDaysOfWeekForClasses(textBoxClassDays.Text.Trim());
  List<DateTime> scheduledClasses = new List<DateTime>();
  int curClassCount = 0;
  DateTime tempDate = StartDate.Date;
  while (curClassCount < totalNumberOfClassesNeeded) {
    if (ClassDaysOfWeek.Contains(tempDate.DayOfWeek)) {
      scheduledClasses.Add(tempDate.Date);
      curClassCount++;
    }
    tempDate = tempDate.AddDays(1);
  }
  txtBoxResults.Text = "";
  txtBoxResults.Text = "Start Date: " + StartDate.ToShortDateString() +Environment.NewLine;
  for (int i = 0; i < scheduledClasses.Count; i++) {
    txtBoxResults.Text += "Class # " + (i + 1) + " of " + totalNumberOfClassesNeeded +
                          " Date: " + scheduledClasses[i].ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine;
  }
}
```

A note, on the max duration… since the `TimeSpan` only allows hours < 23, we need to break 50 hours into 2 days and 2 hours. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This is a great one. I need to test this out too. Your output of list of classes with their dates looks somewhat easier for me than struggling with number of conditions in my partial views. Thanks for taking time to write this answer...

Comment: Since your answer has a level up explanation than the one I asked for and since I found this as a bit cleaner, easier and efficient avoiding condition complexities. I am going forward with this approach. Thanks for the answer..

Comment: Actually I forgot to tell you that, the class duration is different for different days! its not the same. Monday can have some value which may not be the same as tuesday or wednesday.. I need to sort this out on my own. Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

These are two options (using `For` and using `While` loop), should solve the problem:

```
using System;

namespace SO.DtProblem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClaculationOption1(); //Using For loop
            ClaculationOption2(); //Using While loop
        }

        private static void ClaculationOption1()
        {
            var totalWeeks = 0;
            var totalHoursPerWeek = 3;
            var durationPerDay = 3;
            var maxHours = 50;
            var courseStartDate = new DateTime(2021, 4, 12); //Which is a Monday day

            totalWeeks = maxHours / totalHoursPerWeek;

            var expectedEndDate = courseStartDate.AddDays(totalWeeks * 7);

            var pendingHours = maxHours % totalHoursPerWeek;

            for (var day = 1; day <= 6; day++)
            {
                if (pendingHours > 0)
                {
                    expectedEndDate = expectedEndDate.AddDays(1);

                    if ((expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    || (expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                    || (expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday))
                    {
                        if (pendingHours - durationPerDay >= 0)
                        {
                            pendingHours = pendingHours - durationPerDay;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pendingHours = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Option 1 Results");
            Console.WriteLine($"Course Start Date : {courseStartDate}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Course Start Date Day Name: {courseStartDate.DayOfWeek}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected End Date : {expectedEndDate}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected End Date Day Name: {expectedEndDate.DayOfWeek}");
            Console.WriteLine("===========================================================");

        }

        private static void ClaculationOption2()
        {
            var totalWeeks = 0;
            var totalHoursPerWeek = 3;
            var durationPerDay = 3;
            var maxHours = 50;
            var courseStartDate = new DateTime(2021, 4, 12); //Which is a Monday day

            totalWeeks = maxHours / totalHoursPerWeek;

            var expectedEndDate = courseStartDate.AddDays(totalWeeks * 7);

            var pendingHours = maxHours % totalHoursPerWeek;

            while (pendingHours > 0)
            {
                expectedEndDate = expectedEndDate.AddDays(1);

                if ((expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                || (expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
                || (expectedEndDate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday))
                {
                    if (pendingHours - durationPerDay >= 0)
                    {
                        pendingHours = pendingHours - durationPerDay;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pendingHours = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Option 2 Results");
            Console.WriteLine($"Course Start Date : {courseStartDate}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Course Start Date Day Name: {courseStartDate.DayOfWeek}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected End Date : {expectedEndDate}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected End Date Day Name: {expectedEndDate.DayOfWeek}");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Thameem , code has been updated (Console statement corrected)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Useme Alehosaini I'll check this and come back

Comment: I assume I may be missing something, however, when I run your posted code, it gives the final end result as “08/03/2021”? … this can not be correct. If the classes meet three (days) a week (Mon, Tues, Wed), and each class is 3 hours long, then that would be nine (9) hours per week. If the max was 50 hours, then, that would be 5.555 weeks. So, rounding to six (6) weeks to reach the max hours. Given the start date is “4/12/2021”, then six weeks after that date would be sometime in “5/XX/2021.”

Comment: If the three-hour meeting day was only ONE day a week, then it would end sometime in the month of eight (8) but your code appears to be checking for Mon, Tues, and Wed? I am guessing that the line… `var totalHoursPerWeek = 3;` … should be… `var totalHoursPerWeek = 9;` Since there are three (3) classes a week with each class being three (3) hour long. Again, I may be missing something.

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini Thanks for taking time to write this answer. Though this might answer my original question. I am going forward with the OP since that is a way diff approach than my current system arch..

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got my own solution working on the idea based on @John's answer. This answer is specially for the variable hours and minutes.

```
private static void CalculateClassDates()
{
    DateTime courseStartDateTime = DateTime.Today;
    int courseDurationInHours = 60;
    int courseDurationInMinutes = 0;

    TimeSpan courseMaxDuration = new TimeSpan(courseDurationInHours, courseDurationInMinutes, 0);
    List<CourseScheduleDates> courseScheduleDates = new List<CourseScheduleDates>();

    List<DaysOfWeek> daysOfWeeks = new List<DaysOfWeek>()
            {
                new DaysOfWeek(){ DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday, StartTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).TimeOfDay , TotalHours = 1, TotalMinutes = 15},
                new DaysOfWeek(){ DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday, StartTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).TimeOfDay , TotalHours = 1, TotalMinutes = 15},
                new DaysOfWeek(){ DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Wednesday, StartTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10).TimeOfDay , TotalHours = 1, TotalMinutes = 30}
            };

    int daysToAdd = 0;
    TimeSpan singleDuration = new TimeSpan(daysOfWeeks[0].TotalHours, daysOfWeeks[0].TotalMinutes, 0);

    TimeSpan additionallyAddedTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    List<DayOfWeek> days = daysOfWeeks.Select(x => x.DayOfWeek).ToList();
    while (singleDuration.Ticks <= courseMaxDuration.Ticks)
    {
        if (days.Contains(courseStartDateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd).DayOfWeek))
        {
            var dayOfWeek = daysOfWeeks.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == courseStartDateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd).DayOfWeek).First();
            courseScheduleDates.Add(new CourseScheduleDates()
            {
                ScheduleDate = courseStartDateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd),
                StartTime = dayOfWeek.StartTime,
                TotalHours = dayOfWeek.TotalHours,
                TotalMinutes = dayOfWeek.TotalMinutes
            });

            additionallyAddedTime = new TimeSpan(dayOfWeek.TotalHours, dayOfWeek.TotalMinutes, 0);
            singleDuration = singleDuration.Add(additionallyAddedTime);
        }

        daysToAdd++;
    }

    singleDuration = singleDuration.Subtract(additionallyAddedTime);
    if (singleDuration.Ticks != courseMaxDuration.Ticks)
    {
        var timeSpanToAdd = new TimeSpan(courseMaxDuration.Ticks - singleDuration.Ticks);
        bool shouldContinue = true;
        while (shouldContinue)
        {
            var currentDate = courseStartDateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd);
            if (days.Contains(currentDate.DayOfWeek))
            {
                var dayOfWeek = daysOfWeeks.Where(x => x.DayOfWeek == courseStartDateTime.DayOfWeek).First();
                courseScheduleDates.Add(new CourseScheduleDates()
                {
                    ScheduleDate = courseStartDateTime.AddDays(daysToAdd),
                    StartTime = dayOfWeek.StartTime,
                    TotalHours = timeSpanToAdd.Hours,
                    TotalMinutes = timeSpanToAdd.Minutes
                });

                shouldContinue = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Course Start Date " + courseStartDateTime.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy"));

    int classCount = 1;
    foreach (var item in courseScheduleDates)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(item.StartTime.Ticks);
        Console.WriteLine("Class " + classCount + " will commence on " + item.ScheduleDate.ToString("dd MMM, yyyy") +
            " " + dateTime.ToString("hh:mm tt") + " and will last for " + item.TotalHours + " hrs " + item.TotalMinutes + " mins");
        classCount++;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the Models

```
public class DaysOfWeek
{
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public int TotalHours { get; set; }
    public int TotalMinutes { get; set; }
}

public class CourseScheduleDates
{
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public int TotalHours { get; set; }
    public int TotalMinutes { get; set; }
}
```